# CDI Inject Alternatives {identifier not found}

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, glassfish-4

I already checked other posts but nothing seems to solve my trivial issue. Hope you can help me.
I created a J2EE application with NetBeans 8.0.1 and GlassFish 4.1. I have an input.xhtml and a show.xhtml file. (Both are facelets and use template.xthml). In addition I've got a Welcome bean which is using one of two implementations (HelloGreeting or HowdyGreeting) from the Interface Greeting. Since I added the second implementation HowdyGreeting I got the error message shown below.

That's the GlassFish Serverlog:

```
FATAL:   JSF1073: javax.faces.FacesException caught during processing of PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=/input.xhtml @14,102 value="#{welcome.name}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'welcome' resolved to null
FATAL:   /input.xhtml @14,102 value="#{welcome.name}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'welcome' resolved to null
javax.faces.FacesException: /input.xhtml @14,102 value="#{welcome.name}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'welcome' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:84)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /input.xhtml @14,102 value="#{welcome.name}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'welcome' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:95)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1046)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:976)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1249)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'welcome' resolved to null
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:174)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:86)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:201)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:98)
    ... 41 more
```

template.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/default.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/cssLayout.css"/>
        <title>Facelets Template</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <div id="top">
            <ui:insert name="top"><h1>Super Cool App</h1></ui:insert>
        </div>

        <div id="content" class="center_content">
            <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>
        </div>

        <div id="bottom">
            <ui:insert name="bottom"><br/><br/>Powered by GlassFish &amp; NetBeans</ui:insert>
        </div>

    </h:body>

</html>
```

These are the two facelet clients (input and show):

input.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <body>

        <ui:composition template="./WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="content">                
                <h:form>                    
                    <h:panelGrid columns="3">                        
                        <h:outputText value="Name:"/>
                        <h:inputText value="#{welcome.name}" title="name" id="name" required="true"/>
                        <h:message for="name" style="color: red"/>                      
                    </h:panelGrid>                    
                    <h:commandButton action="show" value="submit"/>                
                </h:form>                       
            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>

    </body>
</html>
```

show.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

    <body>

        <ui:composition template="./WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="content">
                <h:outputText value="#{welcome.message}"/>
            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>

    </body>
</html>
```

beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
    <alternatives>
        <class>impl.HelloGreeting</class>
    </alternatives>
</beans>
```

Welcome.java:

```
package beans;

//import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
/**
 * @author Kolling, Denny
 */
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Welcome{
    private String name;
    private String message;

    @Inject Greeting greeting;

    public String getMessage(){
        return greeting.greet(name);
    }
    public void setMessage(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Greeting.java interface:

```
package beans;
/**
 * @author Kolling, Denny
 */
public interface Greeting {
    public String greet(String name);
}
```

HelloGreeting impl.:

```
package impl;

import beans.Greeting;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Alternative;
/**
 * @author Kolling, Denny
 */
@Alternative
public class HelloGreeting implements Greeting{

    @Override
    public String greet(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

HowdyGreeting.java impl.:

```
package impl;

import beans.Greeting;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Alternative;
/**
 * @author Kolling, Denny
 */
@Alternative
public class HowdyGreeting implements Greeting{

    @Override
    public String greet(String name) {
        return "Howdy " + name;
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Try to remove @Alternative from HelloGreeting

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your stackTrace indicates that `welcome` from `<h:inputText value="#{welcome.name}" title="name" id="name" required="true"/>` is not found.

Try to replace :

```
@Named
```

by :

```
@Named("welcome")
```

in your `Welcome.java` bean.

You can also try to specify a `@Default` annotation for one of your `@Alternative` implementation.

See : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjsdf.html (specialization)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try changing your backing bean to a managed bean?

```
@ManagedBean(name = "welcome")
@RequestScoped
public class Welcome{
```

Comment: Then I got a NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you really need to use `@Alternative`. This is only used in very particular cases, e.g. configuration at deployment time.

See documentation : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjsdf.html

> When you have more than one version of a bean you use for different purposes, you can choose between them during the development phase by injecting one qualifier or another.
>
> Instead of having to change the source code of your application, however, you can make the choice at deployment time by using alternatives.

Comment: I need it to handle client-specific business logics later :/